# Pass Variable function name to url_for in flask

Tags: python, flask

Is there any way to change the name of the function inside the **url_for** dynamically according to other parameters in the row of the table. For example, consider the following:

```
{% for ii in User.Channel %}
      <tr>
        <td><b>{{loop.index0+1}}</b></td>
        <td><b>{{ii}}</b></td>
        <td><a href="{{ url_for('variable function depending on ii') }}"> {{ii}}</a></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

Therefore if User.Channel( which is a type class) represents channel name then if ii is 'Youtube' then we go to the Youtube function if ii is 'Google' then we go to Google function. (Just remember ii looks like a string but it is type class.)
One way is to use the if statement I guess but this way is not scalable as we should say

```
if (ii == 'Youtube'):
  href="{{url_for("Youtube")}}"
```

Another method I was thinking is by passing the actual argument to Jinja 2 template like the following:

```
{% for ii in User.Channel %}
      <tr>
        <td><b>{{loop.index0+1}}</b></td>
        <td><b>{{ii}}</b></td>
        <td><a href="{{ url_for('%s'| format(ii)) }}"> {{ii}}</a></td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

Then in view.py I create routes corresponding to name of ii. However I do not know anyway to pass ii as  a string and makes it changing after loop iteration. Above add a "" to the name function as well(since ii is a type class and should be cast to string).

I would really appreciate it if anyone tells me if there is a way to do this(Changing function name dynamically) in the flask or if anyone can suggest a method to implement similar functionalities using a different method.

**EDIT**: **ii** is a type class variable and should be cast to string. It looks like string though. For example ii is 'Youtube', 'Google'.

Comment: If `ii` is a string, have you tried `"{{url_for(ii)}}"`?

Comment: so ii is type class and first need to be cast to strings

Comment: May be you can pass the string `ii` as argument to the method. How about that?

Comment: Probably a way better way to do this, but you could try get the class name as a string with `ii.__class__.__name__`

Comment: @PGHE Maybe I did not understand you. How is this supposed to help? Assume class name as a string.